# Observable merge() detect which observable is triggered

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable

I'm creating a list of `Observable` using a list of values, foreach value a custom `Observable`. I run them all using merge, but I can't detect which one triggers `onNext()` or `onError()`

Like in the code below:

```
 List<Observable<MyHttpRsObj>> observables = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String param : paramsList) {
        Observable<MyHttpRsObj> objObservable = MyRestClient.get().doHttpRequest(param);
        observables.add(fileUploadObservable);
    }

    Observable<BaseRs> combinedObservables = Observable.merge(observables);

    combinedObservables.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyHttpRsObj>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    //called only once when all Observables finished
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    //how to know which Observable has error (which param)
                }


                @Override
                public void onNext(MyHttpRsObj myHttpRsObj) {
                    //how to know which Observable has sccess  (which param)
                }
            });
```

Comment: In each observable coming form `doHttpRequest` do doOnError get exception and wrap it with your custom exception that is having also a `param ` inside. As for the success, you can do the same trick, but use map instead and return `MyHttpRsObj` and `param` inside.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to know which obsevable triggered the error since you merge all observables into single one.

your best bet is to use one observer for each observable. And a last one for merged Observable.

Like this:

```
 List<Observable<MyHttpRsObj>> observables = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String param : paramsList) {
        //change to connectable Observable
        ConnectableObservable<MyHttpRsObj> objObservable = MyRestClient.get()
                 .doHttpRequest(param)
                 .publish();

       //don't forget to connect
        observable.connect();
        observables.add(fileUploadObservable);

        //subscribe for each observable
        objObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyHttpRsObj>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        //just partial completed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        //you can access param from here

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onNext(MyHttpRsObj myHttpRsObj) {
                        //access onNext here
                        //you can access param from here
                    }
                });
    }

    Observable<BaseRs> combinedObservables = Observable.merge(observables);

    combinedObservables.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyHttpRsObj>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    //called only once when all Observables finished
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    //don't handle error here
                }


                @Override
                public void onNext(MyHttpRsObj myHttpRsObj) {

                }
            });
```

*PS*: use [ConnectableObservable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators) to avoid emitting twice

Comment: **NO**, this method just execute each request 2 times! No reason from `merge()` here.